# mvc4 get results in controller from joining tables (entity framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am not sure how to get the results from joining the tables in controllers.
There're 3 tables 'Groups' 'Users' 'GroupUser' (bridge table).

```
public class Group
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public string Group_Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string User_Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have this EFContext class

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
                .HasMany(g => g.Users)
                .WithMany(u => u.Groups)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("UserID");
                    m.MapRightKey("GroupID");
                    m.ToTable("GroupUSer");
                });
```

Do I also need to build a GroupUser class (to represent the GroupUser bridge table)?

Then how do I get the results when joining the 3 tables to get list of groups and users?

```
GroupViewModel model = new GroupViewModel
            {
                Groups = .... // this should be a linq statement that get results 
                that contains all groups and users
            };
```

The equal sql statemen would be

```
select *
from Group g 
join GroupUser gu on g.GroupID=gu.GroupID
join User u on u.UserID=gu.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

No, intermediate class is not needed.

The main point of an ORM (Object-Relational Mapper, which is what Entity Framework is) is to abstract away the database and let you work in a pure object-oriented way. Intermediate tables are definitely a database term and are not needed here.

The only reason I can think of that may lead you to create an intermediate class is when you need a "payload" (an extra meta-data) on the association. For example:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Email { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you want the user-to-account association to define whether the association is of "Own the account" type (Administrator), you can do something like:

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Email { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<AccountUserAssociation> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<AccountUserAssociation> Users { get; set; }
}

public class AccountUserAssociation
{
     public virtual User User { get; set; }
     public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
     public AssociationType AssociationType { get; set; }
}

public enum AssociationType { Regular, Administrator }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! can you also show how to get results from linq? i tried the linq join systax but since the bridge table is not needed. I dont know how to join without the bridge table

Comment: from u in ctx.Users
select u.Group.Group_Name, u.User_Name

Comment: What's the exact results you need?